# Export the map plotted in R to QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, export, plot

I want the map plotted in R to be export in QGIS.

The data source that I used for coding in R is as follows:-

For Raster:-**https://download.hermes.com.np/land-cover-map-of-nepal-2010/.**

For Vector :-**https://cellapp.co/download-nepals-new-map-vector-image/**.

I use the code given to crop and mask raster file with shapefile.

```
library(terra)
library(raster)
LULC10<-rast('C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/EM/LULC10.tif')
plot(LULC10)
LocalUnitshp<-vect('C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/EM/local_unit.shp')
plot(LocalUnitshp)
Rupandehi<-LocalUnitshp[LocalUnitshp$DISTRICT =="RUPANDEHI"]
plot(Rupandehi)
Rupandehi<-project(Rupandehi,LULC10)
plot(mask(crop(LULC10,Rupandehi),Rupandehi))
plot(Rupandehi, add = T)
```

The result obtained is:-
[image]

Now, I want this plotted map to be exported in QGIS so that I can perform other calculations on it. I only exported the file in tiff format. In which file formats does this need to be exported. I encountered an error as shown below in R (when file path to R directory was also correct) when trying to work on exported file.

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = 
"RasterLayer",  : 
Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

Comment: You added all the code but the function that gives you an error. `writeRaster(mask(crop(LULC10,Rupandehi),Rupandehi), 'path/to/file.tfi')` should work

Comment: @aldo_tapia I wrote the code to save the raster to file name Final just below the end of the code above as:-`writeRaster(mask(crop(LULC10,Rupandehi),Rupandehi), 'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/EM/Final.tif') `.                                                                   
But the result displays as:- Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
 error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'writeRaster': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mask': [crop] cannot get a SpatExtent from y.

Comment: This is bad: `Rupandehi<-LocalUnitshp[LocalUnitshp$DISTRICT =="RUPANDEHI"]`. change it to `Rupandehi<-LocalUnitshp[LocalUnitshp$DISTRICT =="RUPANDEHI",]`

Comment: When you say "export the map" do you really mean the entire plotted map graphic, or do you just want the cropped/masked raster **data** so you can load that as a raster layer in QGIS? (Note you can also do this cropping/masking in QGIS itself without needing R)

Comment: @Spacedman,My problem is solved as per the suggestion of aldo_tapia.